# 中学生 why not secondary student life?

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context

As 生 means life I thought 中学生 = secondary study life.

But actual meaning of 中学生  is Secondary School Student.  xuésheng is student, so I remember it as student.

Why it is student rather study life?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

0. 中學生活 does mean 'secondary school life', 中學生 however must mean 'secondary school student'.
1. 生 is a compound ideogram comprising 屮 (sprout) and 一 (ground). A sprout emerging from the ground therefore symbolises life and growth.
2. Besides meaning life (as in 生命), living (as in 生活), growth (as in 生長) etc., 生 has a few other noteworthy derived meanings. 生 in 中學生 corresponds to the second row:

| Definition | Example |
| --- | --- |
| *n.* the living | 養育**眾生** lit. to feed *everyone that is alive* |
| *n.* the literati, the learned, pupil | 學生, 生徒 (retained in Japanese), 諸生 (obsolete) |
| *n.* nature; fundamental character (now replaced by 性) | 天性 (天生 in classical Chinese) |
| *adj.* raw | **生**魚片 lit. *raw* fish slices |

3. The above is an incomplete list, only there to give you an impression of how diverse in meaning 生 can be. I also found a few remarks online that suggest pupils are like sprouts, as they 'grow' and 'absorb knowledge'; reasonable as they may seem, I however do not know how etymologically sound this justification is, as 生 has a long tradition of being a laudatory title for the literati in general (子 as well, as in 孔子 Confucius, 孟子 Mencius; surely one cannot interpret it as 'son'). But if this is good for memorisation, then by all means!

Answer (score 2):

Most characters have multiple meanings, some can act as a noun, verb, or adjective.  生 is a character like this

For '生' to specifically mean 'life', it has to join another character to form a compound word like 人生(one's life/ human's life), 生命(life), 生涯(duration of one's life)

Notice: 生 in 此生(this life) is shortened form of 人生

'学生' is a compound word for 'student'

'中学生' literally means '中学(学)生' with the repeated character 学 omitted.

Similarly:

小學生 = 小學學生

大學生 = 大學學生

重考生 = 重考考生

*重考 (takes the exam again) + 考生 (examinee) = 重考生 (examinee who takes the exam again)*